# Python split and csv; Modification of existing Python Script

Tags: python, csv, split

Another users was kind enough to help me with a script that reads in a file and removes/replaces '::' and moves columns to headers:
(I am reposting as it may be useful to someone in this form- my question follows)

```
with open('infile', "rb") as fin, open('outfile', "wb") as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        split = [item.split("::") for item in line if item.strip()]
        if not split: # blank line
            continue
        keys, vals = zip(*split)
        if i == 0:
            # first line: write header
            writer.writerow(keys)
        writer.writerow(vals)
```

I was not aware that the last column of this file had the following text at the end:

```
{StartPoint::7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075},{EndPoint::7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298}
```

How do I modify this existing code to take the above and:
1. remove the brackets { }
2. convert the '[%2C]' to a ',' - making it comma delim like the rest of the file
3. Produce 'Xa Ya Za' and 'Xb Yb Zb' as headers for the values liberated in #2

The above text is the input file.  Output from the original script produces this:

```
{StartPoint,EndPoint}
7858.35924983374[%2C]1703.69341358077[%2C]-3.075, 7822.85045874375[%2C]1730.80294308742[%2C]-3.53962362760298}
```

Is it possible to insert a simple strip command in there?

Thanks, I appreciate your guidance - I am a Python newbie

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for the `replace` method on strings: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Perhaps something like this after the `zip`:

```
keys = [key.replace('{', '') for key in keys]
vals = [val.split('[%2C]') for val in vals]
```

I'm not sure if csv.writer will handle a nested list like would be in vals after this, but you get the idea. If so, vals should be a flat list. Perhaps something like this would flatten it out:

```
vals = [item for sublist in vals for item in sublist]
```

Comment: Thanks Ari.  I am trying to implement that, but seem to be getting my order/syntax wrong.  Any advice you can offer on how/where to insert it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a few options - you can change the input to csv.reader() before calling that, you can loop through each key & value before writing it, or you can use StringIO to have csv.writerow() output to a string and then you can do the replacement there before printing it out. The best solution here would probably be to just loop through the keys & values, so I just edited my answer to include an example of that.